# Is it possible to boot into another device from Windows? (skipping the BIOS boot menu)

Tags: windows, boot, bios

I was wondering if there was a way to tell Windows/the BIOS to boot to a different device upon reboot. Here's what I want to do:

1. Plug in a bootable memory stick
2. Run a script of some kind to reboot into it

Sorry for the terrible explanation and thanks for the help :)

Comment: No, it's not possible. If UEFI you can reboot to the firmware and from there choose a different boot device but that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but only with UEFI-based Windows 8+ installations. Unfortunately, there is a caveat: You will only be able to select devices the UEFI firmware has detecting during its startup sequence. So if you plug in a USB drive while Windows is already running, it will not be selectable.

You’ll need to use the “Advanced Reboot” menu. It’s easiest to bring up by holding down shift while selecting the “Reboot” option in the Start Menu. From there, select “Use a device”. You’ll see a screen similar to this one:

[image]

From here, select the desired device and Windows will instruct the UEFI firmware to boot from this device *once*. After that, it will return to the regular boot order as set in the firmware setup.

Comment: This is so much easier in Linux. Just edit the "next boot" EFIvar, then reboot.

Answer (score -1):

The only way this is possible if in the BIOS/EFI you set that device as topmost
in the boot order.

Use the `shutdown` command with the `-r` parameter to cause a reboot.
If a rebootable device is mounted then it will boot, and if not then the
boot will fall-back to the hard disk.

The downside of this is that you need to remember to remove the stick when you
don't want to boot into it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are wrong. All UEFI systems has UEFIvars. One of those is the "boot next" variable. If you plug in your device before powering on, and are then able to change the value of the variable, you can boot into what ever UEFI device you want to just by selecting reboot computer.

Comment: @svin83: This method does not answer the post, although accepted by the poster. The post asked for a script, and the accepted method is not a script.

Comment: The UEFI variables CAN be changed with scripts. You get dedicated tools for this in Linux and on BSD. But I know for a fact it can also be done in Windows 8.x/10 with some PowerShell scripting-magic.

Comment: @svin83: What does this change here?